# Replacing values in the columns of a matrix according to a vector of indices?

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have a matrix of zeroes:

```
M <- matrix(0, nrow = 10, ncol = 5)
```

and a vector of indices

```
V <- c(1,5,3,2,3,4,1,3,2,4)
```

I want to replace the entries `M[i,V[i]]` by 1, i in 1:10. How can I do this without using brute force (for loop)? Below is the code to do so using brute force, which is not efficient in higher dimensions:

```
for(i in 1:10) M[i,V[i]] = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a matrix from your vector V and use it directly, i.e.

```
M[matrix(c(seq_along(V), V), ncol = 2)] <- 1
```